# view exposed filter ajax error coming for non administrator user

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I have *event calendar module* which is perfectly working fine. For some other users (*non-admin* users) I have to give permission to access events posted by them (They have permission to view the calendar and add/modify/delete events).

So far everything is good. Now I added *exposed filter*(event status) which is working as expected while I logged in as *admin*.
Only when I login as user with some other role, I'm getting:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /views/ajax
StatusText: OK
```

Why is this happening only to non-admin user? I thought bypassing access control can give me some hint if its permission issue so I gave *'Bypass views access control'* to that particular user role, still no luck. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you get with "Use Ajax" turned off in views advance configurations?

Comment: @arpitr: when I turned it off, page loads and results are coming as expected. But I dont want to turn it off, wanted it to be ajax operation

Comment: I am afraid if issue lies in your theme, try changing the theme for non-admin user to use admin theme and see if issue persists.

Comment: did this help you? or you got the solution?

Comment: @arpitr how do I change the theme for non-admin user?

Comment: visit admin/appearance after login as admin and set "seven" as set default. I assume you might be using seven as admin theme you can check what your admin theme is,on admin/appearance page scroll down to bottom to find "Administration theme"

Comment: if I do that, it'll affect the whole site not for just that particular user role that having this issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10884/discussion-between-arpitr-and-pown)

Comment: is this problem specific to a particular user role?
if so issue might be becuase of permission
do not set the theme in that case

Answer (score 0):

Go to Views Ui Setting Tab on Advance and uncheck Javascript ...
it's Work for me